# Most eloquent way of writing a group of tap gesture recognizers that do similar things

Tags: ios, swift, function, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have 9 views with 9 tap gesture recognizers that all do very similar tasks. I've been raking my brain to think of a more eloquent way of writing this but haven't been able to come up with anything. Any help would be very appreciated!

```
func flipToBack(){
    let matrix = Animations.HotSpotNumber(rawValue: currentHotSpot)
    guard let dict = matrix?.instructions else {return}
    flipLayerSecondPhaseWithInstructions(dict, layer: frontView.layer, directionOfTransformation: "towardsBackSide")
}

func flipToFront(){
    let matrix = Animations.HotSpotNumber(rawValue: currentHotSpot)
    guard let dict = matrix?.instructions else {return}
    flipLayerSecondPhaseWithInstructions(dict, layer: frontView.layer, directionOfTransformation: "towardsFrontSide")
}


func handleBackSideTap(){
    let animation = Animations.HotSpotNumber(rawValue: currentHotSpot)
    guard let dict = animation?.instructions else {return}
    flipLayerFirstPhaseWithInstructions(dict, layer: frontView.layer, directionOfTransformation: "towardsFrontSide")
}

func handleHotSpotOneTap(){
    let dict = Animations.HotSpotNumber.One.instructions
    currentHotSpot = 1
    flipLayerFirstPhaseWithInstructions(dict, layer: frontView.layer, directionOfTransformation: "towardsBackSide")
}

func handleHotSpotTwoTap(){
    let dict = Animations.HotSpotNumber.Two.instructions
    currentHotSpot = 2
    flipLayerFirstPhaseWithInstructions(dict, layer: frontView.layer, directionOfTransformation: "towardsBackSide")
}

func handleHotSpotThreeTap(){
    let dict = Animations.HotSpotNumber.Three.instructions
    currentHotSpot = 3
    flipLayerFirstPhaseWithInstructions(dict, layer: frontView.layer, directionOfTransformation: "towardsBackSide")
}

func handleHotSpotFourTap(){
    let dict = Animations.HotSpotNumber.Four.instructions
    currentHotSpot = 4
    flipLayerFirstPhaseWithInstructions(dict, layer: frontView.layer, directionOfTransformation: "towardsBackSide")
}

func handleHotSpotSixTap(){
    let dict = Animations.HotSpotNumber.Six.instructions
    currentHotSpot = 6
    flipLayerFirstPhaseWithInstructions(dict, layer: frontView.layer, directionOfTransformation: "towardsBackSide")

}

func handleHotSpotSevenTap(){
    let dict = Animations.HotSpotNumber.Seven.instructions
    currentHotSpot = 7
    flipLayerFirstPhaseWithInstructions(dict, layer: frontView.layer, directionOfTransformation: "towardsBackSide")
}

func handleHotSpotEightTap(){
    let dict = Animations.HotSpotNumber.Eight.instructions
    currentHotSpot = 8
    flipLayerFirstPhaseWithInstructions(dict, layer: frontView.layer, directionOfTransformation: "towardsBackSide")
}

func handleHotSpotNineTap(){
    let dict = Animations.HotSpotNumber.Nine.instructions
    currentHotSpot = 9
    flipLayerFirstPhaseWithInstructions(dict, layer: frontView.layer, directionOfTransformation: "towardsBackSide")
}
```

Comment: Those hardcoded `.One` ... `.Nine` values should really be `Int` indexes into an array

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that in an enum. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a single function (or even an extension) that accepts a couple parameters to specify the task. Then instead of writing out an entire function for each of these recognizers, you could just call one and specify the parameters for the task.

Answer (score 0):

Without know what your source for `Animations.HotSpotNumber.Four.instructions` looks like it would be tough to say the best way but you could do something like the following.

```
var arrayOfInstructions: [[String: String]] = [["first": "inst"],["second":"inst"]]

func animateForTap(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let instructions = arrayOfInstructions[sender.tag]
    flipLayerFirstPhaseWithInstructions(instructions, layer: frontView.layer, directionOfTransformation: "towardsBackSide")
```

then you could set the tag property on the Tap recognizers to the appropriate int value and have all of them respond to this selector.

Comment: got it. I ended up  subclassing UIButton instead of UIView to set the animation triggers and then set the tag to UIButton. thanks!